# UK: Is there a difference between Renter's, Tenant's and Contents Insurance?

Tags: united-kingdom, insurance

I'm in the UK, needing to get some insurance for my possessions, and I'm getting confused by the terminology in trying to do so.

When I search for tenant's insurance or renter's insurance, I can generally find some results. Following the link through to get a quote invariably sends me to an all-purpose home insurance page (with the option to choose only contents). I've read somewhere that contents insurance is subtly different to renter's/tenant's (something about exactly whom it covers), but I'm just getting lost trying to figure it all out now.

In short then, as per the title:

**Is there a difference between Tenant's, Renter's and Contents Insurance** (in the UK)?

## UPDATE

Having been home and had a look at the tenancy agreement, is seems to say that what I'm required to have is contents insurance, but with 3rd party cover on the landlord's possessions / furniture / fixtures / fittings (which is usually not included in standard contents insurance policies). Is this the same thing as liability insurance (as mentioned by Chad below)?

I'm still not sure if this is the difference, so any further info is still appreciated.

Comment: Call an agent.  Get a renters policy.  Tell them to make sure you have landlord owned contents included.  (it should be anyway).  The cost to include your contents with the landlords will be minimal.  And will add the liability coverage as well.  Liablity steps in when you start a fire (accidentally) on your stove that causes pain and suffering to your neighbors(for example).  The liability coverage would protect you in the event you get sued. It may not be required but it wraps into the coverage dirt cheap (probably at no extra cost if you take the standard coverage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the US(and apparently the UK), Renters insurance is an umbrella policy that generally includes some liability coverage in case of damages caused by the insured as well as coverage for contents, and often includes a stipend to cover expenses from finding temporary shelter should it be needed.

Contents insurance just covers the property owned by/in possession of the insured.  This can be limited by type of damage, so if you are on the top floor you do not need to worry as much about flooding, as if you are on a lower floor. But the savings are generally very small.  On a 100k policy in the US typically the difference between renters and content coverage is less than $20 a year.  Typically content coverage is for people with valuable assets(original artwork, jewelry, etc) in excess of what standard liability and property coverage would be needed.  This would usually be purchased in addition to a rental or owners policy.  Though you could choose to protect your contents with out a liability protection policy.

Tenant coverage appears to be the equivalent of the General Liability policy in the US.  It would protect the tenant from liability in case of damage caused by them to the rental property or other tenants.